# Help for making Complex List View

Tags: android

I am having a problem creating ListView. Its a complex ListView with each row having 1 imageview and 2 textviews.It looks something like this:

The row has 1 image on the left and the 2 texts are on the right of the image one below the other and within the height of the image

Can anybody guide me on this.
The 2 texts will keep on changing for each row.
Texts are stored in a string array.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below [this](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) or [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-1) or [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html)